# Manufacturer codes for E0 RFID tags

Tags: rfid

I have an RFID tag and I would like to know the manufacturer. According to [RFID journal](http://www.rfidjournal.com/expert/entry/8523), the E0 format uses an 8-bit manufacturer ID. I've got this code. Is there some table where I can look up the manufacturer?

Please note, I'm not looking for the table of E2 manufacturers

Answer (score 3):

A complete list of manufacturer codes used in ISO 15693 (uses the E0-format) and ISO 14443 tags (the ones with 7-byte IDs) can be found at http://www.kartenbezogene-identifier.de/de/chiphersteller-kennungen.html